# How set default value for a property using CodeFirst WITHOUT editing the generated migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to set default value for some properties in a POCO class. however I rather not to change manually the generated migrations.

Is there any annotation or command in OnModelCreating that can set some default values for those properties?

Comment: Please don't confuse the Presentation layer [tag:asp.net-mvc] framework with data access [tag:entity-framework] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EF6, properties value can be configured in OnModelCreating method of FluentAPI.
Suppose I have User class and I want Country property always USA.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "Country").Configure(x => x.ClrPropertyInfo.SetValue(currentInstanceOfUser, "USA"));
    }
}
```

You need to pass value of 'currentInstanceOfUser' in above code. I tried sever ways but not successful.